# Running Two sp_executesql

Tags: entity-framework, t-sql

I am encountering this situation where EF6 is used to save an object to the database (into 2 separate tables). Thus, by executing `SaveChanges()` in EF, this generated 2 seperate `exec sp_executesql insert...` statements.

This is where the value generated from the first insert will be used as an input parameter to the second statement.

One thing I noticed though is that when the second statement failed in one case, no records were written.

I pulled up SQL-Profiler and did not see any rollbacks being made either; can't seem to figure out how this rollback actually occurred.

Appreciate any advice pls.

Comment: I bet that transaction is being maintained in an entirely different scope than what you are seeing. I would bet the SqlConnection or TransactionScope is being used to maintain transactions and respond to sql errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One thing I noticed though is that when the second statement failed in one case, no records were written.
>
> I pulled up SQL-Profiler and did not see any rollbacks being made either; can't seem to figure out how this rollback actually occurred.

By calling `SaveChanges()` on your EF context, all modifications made to your entities (insert, update, delete etc) are wrapping into a single SQL transaction. This is a default behavior in EF.

The purpose of a transaction is to take all the SQL statements as a single operation, a unit of work. If one statement fails at the middle or at the end then all passed statements are rollback even those that are executed successfully.

To prevent this you can call `SaveChanges()` separately for each changes you made in your EF context.